# Run adb pipe commands in python

Tags: python, pipe, adb, popen

I have been trying to run the adb command below through python script:

```
'ls -1r | grep -m1 house | xargs tail -n2'
```

note that before this line I've already navigate to the right directory within the adb shell, and I've manually tested the command it worked as expected. After doing some research I've made the following attempts:

Using getoutput:

```
output = commands.getoutput('ls -1r | grep -m1 house | xargs tail -n2')
```

Using Popen:

```
args0 = ['ls','-1r']
args1 = ['grep','-m1','house']
args2 = ['xargs','tail','-n2']
p0 = Popen(args0, shell=True, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
p1 = Popen(args1, shell=True,stdin=p0.stdout, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(args2, shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
(output,stderr) = p2.communicate()
```

But the output/stderr is either `NONE` or `''`. I've also tried removing the `shell=True`, or put `p0.stdout.close()` before the communicate() line, also doesn't do anything.

Not sure why it's not working, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run adb commands through subprocess. Make sure the command chain is valid

```
subprocess.check_output(["adb", "shell", "ls -1r | grep -m1 house | xargs tail -n2"])
```

Comment: I tried this `subprocess.check_output(["ls -1r | grep -m1 house | xargs tail -n2"])` but it throw me an error says "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" . Also I need to obtain the output instead of just running it